# npm WARN ngx-qrcode2@0.0.9 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, npm

I want to make circle progress bar in ionic. I am install `npm install angular-svg-round-progressbar@1.0.7 --save` but i get error

- npm WARN ngx-qrcode2@0.0.9 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
- npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
  npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
- angular-svg-round-progressbar@1.0.7
  added 6 packages from 8 contributors, removed 1 package, updated 1 package and audited 55060 packages in 48.245s
  found 34 high severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

[This is My angular version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NTSj.jpg)

Comment: The solution is literally in the warnings

Comment: Thank you for answer, can you give me example for solution in the warning, please?

Comment: If a specific packages requires a peer of another package. Install that package........

Comment: i have install npm install -g npm-install-peers but still error

Comment: can you try `npm i -f`

Comment: @Fearcoder i have npm i -f
but i get same error

Answer (score 0):

Simply run those

```
npm install @angular/core@6.0.3
npm install fsevents
npm audit fix
```